# What does $S^1 \setminus \{{pt}\}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, terminology

In [this](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/banachtarski.pdf) paper, expression $S^1 \setminus \{{pt}\}$ is used on page 6. The $\{{pt}\}$ is not definied there. What does it mean and is it a standard notation?

Comment: It's what you get from removing a point from $S^1$. "pt" being short for "point".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means the circle minus any point. They choose the notation $ \{pt\} $ because the specific point is irrelevant, so the author chose not to specify one.

Answer (score 2):

Its $S^1$ with a point removed. $S^1$ is symmetric so the point can be chosen arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

It is called as cut point for circle i.e removing one point from circle.